# Insert corresponding data in another field when radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, onclick

Insert corresponding data in another field when `radio` button is clicked

**For e.g**

```
+---------+-----------+------+
|  Name   | Phone No  |tick  |
+---------+-----------+------+
|   AB    | 67890     |  o   |
+---------+-----------+------+
|   CD    | 12345     |  o   |
+---------+-----------+------+

        __________
phone  |__________|  (textbox/textarea)
```

when i click on the radio button (suppose i click on the first one) the corresponding phone number (67890) should insert in the textbox below.These data are loaded from the database.
I have tried `onclick` in javascript but didn't work in php i guess.

Please help

My codes are

```
<?php
    include("data.php");

    echo"<table border='1'>";
    $result=@mysql_query("SELECT *from t");

                    echo "<form>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
            {
                echo"<tr align='left'>";
                echo"<th><font color='black'>name";
                echo"<th><font color='black'>phone";
                echo"<th><font color='black'>Tick";
                echo "</tr></thead>";
                $a=0;
                while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {

                    $a=$a+1;
                    echo "<tbody>";
                    echo"<td><input type='text' name='phone[$a]' value=$test[ph]></td>";
                    echo"<td>".$test['name']."</td>";
                    echo"<td><input type='checkbox' name='tick' onclick='fill(this.form,$a)'></td>";

                    echo "</tr></tbody>";

                }
                echo"</table>";


            echo"<td></br><input type='text' name='sec_phone'></td>";
            echo "</form>";
                mysql_close($conn);
            }
            ?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function fill(f,a) {
  if(f.tick.checked == true) {
    f.sec_phone.value = f.phone[a].value;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: plesae write your php code which you tried

Comment: I have entered my codes Thanks in advance

Comment: change <input type='checkbox' to <input type='radio'

Comment: changed but not working

Answer (score 0):

here my code hope it help your problem

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VZepQ/)

### html

```
<form action="">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Phone No</td>
    <td>tick</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td><div id="phone_1">67890</div></td>
    <td>
    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="Check_1" >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CD</td>
    <td><div id="phone_2">12345</div></td>
    <td>
    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="Check_2" >
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>
<input type="text" value="">
```

### js

```
$( "#Check_1" ).click(function() {
  var text = $( "#phone_1" ).text();

  $( "input" ).val( text );
});

$( "#Check_2" ).click(function() {
  var text = $( "#phone_2" ).text();

  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
```

Comment: But the data are coming from database